# How do I know if a predictor changing signs is genuine?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multicollinearity

Imagine that predictor A has a positive relationship with the dependent variable and that it also has a high correlation with predictor B.

When predictors A and B are entered into a regression model together suppose that predictor A now has a negative relationship with the dependent variable.

This seems like a symptom of multicollinearity. But, could it ever be the case that after controlling for predictor B, the unique variance in the dependent variable explained by predictor A had a negative relationship with that predictor? Can a predictor ever genuinely switch signs like in the example given? Are there ways to tell whether a sign flip is genuine or a symptom of multicollinearity?

(I imagine people will take issue my use of "genuine". What I mean is indicative of a genuine negative relationship between the uniquely explained variance and predictor A, and not a product of multicollinearity.)

Comment: Maybe checking for multicollinearity first (e.g., using [variance inflation factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_inflation_factor)) would be helpful. After that you will be more confident in your interpretation.

Comment: The answer is no.  When two regressors are orthogonal, the estimated coefficients in a least squares regression remain the same when one regressor is dropped.  For a worked example, as well as an analysis of this situation that focuses on significance, please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/28493/919.

Answer (score 1):

You ask:

> But, could it ever be the case that after controlling for predictor B,
> the unique variance in the dependent variable explained by predictor A
> had a negative relationship with that predictor? Can a predictor ever
> genuinely switch signs like in the example given?

Yes. This happens often if the variables are not orthogonal. See questions about mediation, also look up spurious correlation.

> Are there ways to tell whether a sign flip is genuine or a symptom of
> multicollinearity?

Well, in a certain sense, the answer is that it is always a product of collinearity, it's just a question of how much collinearity there is and whether it is problematic. If the variables are orthogonal (no collinearity at all) then this can't happen.

Is the amount of collinearity problematic?  There are several ways of checking collinearity. I prefer condition indexes. You can get these in R and SAS and probably other software. I also like the idea of the perturb package in R, but that has been removed from CRAN (I don't know why).

Comment: "Archived on 2020-12-10 as check problems were not corrected in time." (Someone who wanted could presumably adopt the package ... it can also be installed (probably) using `remotes::install_version("perturb", "2.10")`)

Answer (score 0):

> Imagine that predictor A has a positive relationship with the dependent variable

> Can a predictor ever genuinely switch signs like in the example given

The switch is genuine when the final sign is the actual true sign.

You seem to be asking for a case where some predictor A correlates positively with the dependent variable, but it's 'true' sign is negative.

Of course this situation can happen in any model with multiple variables where the negative sign only emerges after including other variables.

An example happens when we have some model

$Y = -a X_1 + b X_2 + \epsilon$

and make $X_2$ positively correlated to $X_1$. In that case the true sign for $X_1$ is negative, but without $X_2$ the variable $X_1$ will take over the role of $X_2$ and gets potentially fitted with a positive parameter (if $b>a$ and the correlation is high).

R-code example:

```r
set.seed(1)
n = 100

### create two correlated variables as features
X = MASS::mvrnorm(n,
                  mu = c(0,0), 
                  Sigma = matrix(c(1,  0.9,
                                   0.9,1  ), 2))

x1 = X[,1]
x2 = X[,2]

### create some dependent variable based on a negative parameter with added noise

y = -1 * x1 + 2 * x2 + rnorm(n)

### fit two models
### one with and one without feature X2

lm(y ~ 1 + x1)
lm(y ~ 1 + x1 + x2)

### output of the two lines above
###
### 
### Coefficients:
### (Intercept)           x1  
###     0.01794      0.80726  
###
###
### Coefficients:
### (Intercept)           x1           x2  
###     0.02535     -0.86962      1.89127 
###
### which shows a clear change of sign for the 'x1' parameter estimate
### and because we know the true model, we know that this sign change is genuine
```

> Are there ways to tell whether a sign flip is genuine or a symptom of multicollinearity?

The above situation shows a sign change that is genuine. I wonder about situations where a sign change, after adding extra predictors, would not be genuine.

The typical situation is that adding extra predictors is making the model more accurate and more 'genuine'.

An interesting related case are the changes in parameter estimates that might occur in regularised regression like the question [Why under joint least squares direction is it possible for some coefficients to decrease in LARS regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236863/) which discusses decreases in the magnitudes of paramtere estimates when regularisation is reduced. Extreme situations occur when parameter estimates decrease in such extent that the change signs, which relates to this question [Geometrical interpretation of why can't ridge regression shrink coefficients to 0?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/587492/) where some of the parameter estimates cross zero for particular intermediate degrees of regularisation.

This makes it difficult to 'tell' whether a parameter estimate (sign change) is genuine. In the complex situations where this situation might occur, this is often less of a problem because the regression is performed for reasons of prediction and less for reasons of hypothesis testing or analysis of theoretical models. On the other hand, the problems of sign changes may occur already very easily when there areodel misspecifications like the situation here: [A misspecification error with linear models that can complete reverse the direction of an effect, has this been described, has this a name?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/575039/)