# Is the Sparsity Pattern (Number of Non Zero Elements) of the Lasso Solution Monotonic as a Function of $ \lambda$?

Tags: regression, lasso, sparse

For solving:

$$\hat\beta^\lambda = \arg\min_{\beta \in \mathbb{R}^p} \|y - X \beta\|_2^2 + \lambda \|\beta\|_1,$$

We know that the values of $ \beta $ might increase for some $ {\lambda}_{2} > {\lambda}_{1} $. Namely they don't monotonic non increasing as $ \lambda $ gets bigger (See [Is there a clear set of conditions under which lasso, ridge, or elastic net solution paths are monotone?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154870/is-there-a-clear-set-of-conditions-under-which-lasso-ridge-or-elastic-net-solu)).

Yet I wonder if the sparsity pattern is monotonic? Will the following hold:

$$ {\lambda}_{2} > {\lambda}_{1} \Leftrightarrow {\left\| \hat {\beta}^{{\lambda}_{2}} \right\|}_{0} \leq {\left\| \hat {\beta}^{{\lambda}_{1}} \right\|}_{0} $$

Where

$$\| \mathbf{x} \|_0 = \# \left\{i : \mathbf{x}_i \neq 0 \right\} $$

Comment: By $\vert\vert\hat\beta\vert\vert_0$, do you mean the number of zero-components?

Comment: @Dave, I tried to clarify this. I meant the number of non zero elements in the vector.

Comment: Search our site for examples of [Lasso trace plots](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=lasso+trace) for counterexamples.  I posted an example at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/452468/919 and pointed out this phenomenon.

Comment: @whuber, Could you post your counter example here? Just change the `x` axis into $ \lambda` and I'll mark it. Thanks!

Comment: @whuber, Why close it? I'd recreate your example here if you allow me.

Comment: No change is needed to that example, so according to your previous comment it answers your question.  We don't need to repost it.

Comment: I'd like to have that answer as a function of $\lambda$ and not the $L_1$ norm.