# LASSO for unit norm parameters?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, linear-model, lasso, regularization

I have the model $y = X\theta +e$, where $\vert\vert \theta\vert\vert =1$ and $e$ are iid normal errors and $\vert\vert\cdot\vert\vert$ represents the Euclidean norm. Can I use a LASSO penalty in this case too? If so, does the fact that the parameters have a unit norm change the approach?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is valid and can be solved by **Projected Gradient Descent**, where we project the solution to L2 ball constraint. Check my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/272578/solving-constrained-optimization-problem-projected-gradient-vs-dual/272928#272928) for details.

In Projected Gradient Decent, the projection step is another optimization problem.In this problem, we want to find a point in $C$ (constraint set), this point is closest to a given point $x^*$. Which is
$$
\underset{x \in C}{\text{arg min}} \|x-x^*\|
$$

In certain cases, this optimization problem is easy to solve and have closed from for example, box constraint or L2 ball. For L2 ball, the solution is:

$$
\underset{x \in C}{\text{arg min}} \|x-x^*\|=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      x^* & \|x^*\| \leq r \\
      r \frac {x^*} {\|x\|} & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{array} 
\right.
$$

The equation tells, if the point is inside of the constraint domain, then the projection is the point itself.

And I will demonstrate the $r \frac {x^*} {\|x\|}$ case graphically, check the points (labeled with numbers) in blue track and red track, the relationship is easy: connect the blue dots with the center of the circle, the intersection with the circle is the projection.

The following figure gives how it works visually: where the red trace is projected gradient decent trace. In the experiment, I set a large $\lambda$ on L1 regularization, and the optimal point is close to the origin. We can clear see the projected solution (red dots) is on the unit circle.

[image]

PS: R code if you want to experiment more.

---

```
fn<-function(x,A,b,l1,l2){
  e=A %*% x - b
  v=crossprod(e)+l2*crossprod(x)+l1*sum(abs(x))
  return(c(v))
}

gr<-function(x,A,b,l1,l2){
  v=t(A) %*% (A %*% x -b)
  return(2*c(v)+2*l2*x+l1*sign(x))
}

set.seed(0)
par(cex=1)
n_data=10
n_feature=2

A=matrix(runif(n_data*n_feature),ncol=n_feature)
b=matrix(runif(n_data),ncol=1)

l1=50
l2=0

# plot obj function
x1=seq(-5,5,0.05)
x2=seq(-5,5,0.05)
d=expand.grid(x1,x2)
f_v=matrix(apply(d,1,fn, A=A, b=b, l1=l1 , l2=l2),nrow=length(x1))
contour(x1,x2,f_v, lwd=3, labcex=1,col='khaki4', xlim=c(-5,5),ylim=c(-5,5))
grid()
constraint_v=outer(x1,x2,function(x,y) x^2+y^2-1)
contour(x1,x2,constraint_v, lwd=3, levels=0, add=T,col="forestgreen",labcex=1.5)

# solve the unconstrained optimization using toolbox
opt_res=optimx::optimx(c(-1,-1),fn, gr, method="BFGS", A=A, b=b, l1=l1 , l2=l2)
opt_x=c(opt_res$p1,opt_res$p2)
points(opt_x[1],opt_x[2],pch=19,col="black")

#-------------------------------------------------------------------
# all algorithms fix step size
# solve unconstrained optimization using gradient decent
x_init=c(-2,-3)
t=0.0001
f_opt=opt_res$value
x=x_init
trace_x=x_init
while(fn(x, A, b, l1 , l2)- f_opt> 1e-2){
  x=x-t*gr(x, A=A, b=b, l1=l1 , l2=l2)
  trace_x=rbind(trace_x,x)
  print(x)
}
# for GD we just plot points not string labels
points(trace_x,type='b',pch=19)


# solve constrained optimization using projected gradient decent
# x_d means desired place to go, x means after projection
x_init=c(-2,-3)
t=0.0001
x=x_init
f_opt=opt_res$value
trace_x=x_init
trace_x_d=x_init

while(fn(x, A, b, l1 , l2)-f_opt>1e-2){
  x_d=x-t*gr(x, A=A, b=b, l1=l1 , l2=l2)
  trace_x_d=rbind(trace_x_d,x_d)

  if(norm(x_d,'2')<1){
    x=x_d
  }
  else{
    x=1*x_d/norm(x_d,'2')
  }
  trace_x=rbind(trace_x,x)
}
trace_x=head(trace_x)
trace_p=head(trace_x_d)

points(trace_x_d,type='b',col=4,pch=19,lwd=3)
points(trace_x,type='b',col=2,pch=19,lwd=3)


legend(1,-0.7,c('obj contour','constraint', 'gd unconstrained',
                 'gd before projection', 'gd after projection'),
       lwd=3,col=c("khaki4",'forestgreen','black','blue','red'))
```

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you're proposing: could you please clarify the definition of $x^*$ and $C$ in the setting of OP's problem?

Comment: @Ben thank you for interested on my answer. I got really busy recently and may not have time to explain in detail. sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

This can likely be solved with the elastic net. Suppose we have response $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and design matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$.

By lagrangian duality, the estimator $$\hat\theta_{(a)} = \arg\min_{\theta \in \mathbb{R}^p \, : \, \|\theta\|_1 \leq C_1, \, \|\theta\|_2 \leq 1} \|y-X\theta\|_2^2$$ is also the minimizer $$\hat\theta_{(b)} = \arg\min_{\theta \in \mathbb{R}^p} \frac{1}{2n} \|y - X \theta\|_2^2 + \lambda \|\theta\|_1 + \mu \|\theta\|_2^2$$ for some dual variables $\lambda$ and $\mu$. That is, $\hat\theta_{(a)} = \hat\theta_{(b)} \left( =: \hat\theta \right)$. That means that all you have to do is tune $\mu$ appropriately to achieve the desired $\ell_2$ norm of the estimate $\hat\theta_{(b)}$. Further, you have to be sure that $\lambda$ is not "too large" to ensure that there exists some $\mu$ so that the estimate $\hat\theta_{(b)}$ can have $\ell_2$ norm equal to one.

The only hitch here is that the estimator you are actually interested in is $$\tilde\theta = \arg\min_{\theta \in \mathbb{R}^p \, : \, \|\theta\|_1 \leq C_1, \, \|\theta\|_2 = 1} \|y-X\theta\|_2^2,$$ and it isn't necessarily true that $\hat\beta = \tilde\beta$.  However, we can see that $\tilde\theta = \hat\theta$ if $\mu \ne 0$ by complementary slackness. (Notice, of course, that this $\mu$ was specifically defined to be the dual variable corresponding to the bound of $1$--it isn't arbitrary.) In general though, it's possible that $\|\hat\theta_{(b)} \|_2 > 1$ for all possible choices of $(\lambda, \mu)$. In which case, the problem you're trying to solve is nonconvex and elastic net would not work: you'd have to do a more complicated optimization method, perhaps like hxd mentions.

It's also worth pointing out that $\|\hat\theta_{(b)}\|_2$ is not necessarily monotonically decreasing with respect to $\lambda$. See, for instance, [Can $\|\beta^*\|_2$ increase when $\lambda$ increases in Lasso?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145299/can-beta-2-increase-when-lambda-increases-in-lasso).